# Spring SpEL to set RequestMapping path with a list

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-el

I want to programmatically set the paths on a rest service.  I have this bean method which has all the paths.

```
public List<String> getSubscribeChannelsForRest() { .. }
```

This is the rest service

```
@RestController
public class RestMessageController {

    @PostMapping(
            path = { "#{somebean.getSubscribeChannelsForRest()[0]}",
                     "#{somebean.getSubscribeChannelsForRest()[1]}",
                     "#{somebean.getSubscribeChannelsForRest()[2]}"
            })
    public String processMessage(@RequestBody String messageBody, HttpServletRequest request) { .. }
```

The above code works but I want to avoid hard coding the array numbers.  There is what I tried.

```
@PostMapping(
            path = { "#{somebean.getSubscribeChannelsForRest()}",
```

This doesn't work because the spring method RequestMappingHandlerMapping.resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(String[] patterns) takes the above SpEL as a single element array.  I've checked the trace logs and all the element in the given list get concatenated .